# ind the consecutive odd whose sum is equal to n**3

Tags: list, consecutive-months

It is known that each number of the form n**3 is equal to the sum of consecutive odd n. For instance:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzZIQ.png)

Given an integer m, m, > 0, find the consecutive odd whose sum is equal to n**3, for n assuming values from 1 to m.

I did this code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQHyp.png)

I'm sorry for the comments being in Portuguese because I'm Brazilian.

Could he stick with a better logic or leaner?

The code is above.
Could he stick with a better logic or leaner?

I built a list with the limit of 1000 integers, then iterated on the odd list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex9iN.png)

Comment: Please don't post [images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) or links to such images. Post these things as text. Use [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your question.

Comment: Re. comments in Portuguese---you may want to write all comments for all your programs in English. You will be showing your code to people from other countries. In fact you are doing this right now.

Comment: Note that there is code review, also: I don't know if you have any guidance, but I will point out you can calculate the list without needing to store everything (especially if you're allowed to print e.g. 13 ... 19 as abbreviated for 13,15,17,19)